# Implement OsmAnd in iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, openstreetmap, osmand

How to implement OsmAnd in my iOS application? I have downloaded sample project from [github](https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd-ios) but I amgetting error while running the code.

I have done R&D on it and understand that I have to implement all necessary repositories from [here](https://github.com/osmandapp) but question is how to do it? Totally confused on what to do?

Reference:  [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/osmand/IB_mEKlhlVw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue.

Please follow below steps to do this,

1. Setup [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/install.php) in Mac Terminal.
2. Fire below commands in terminal

   ```
   sudo port install bash, bzip2, curl, git, ImageMagick +rsvg, librsvg, p7zip, python3*, wget
   ```
3. Install [Google Repo](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html#installing-repo)
4. `mkdir OsmAnd && cd OsmAnd`
5. `repo init -u https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd-manifest -m readonly.xml`
6. `./ios/prepare.sh`
7. `./ios/prebuild-core.sh`

   Open the Xcode and build once again you got an error that

> Implicitly declaring library function 'malloc' with type 'void
>   *(unsigned long)'

For solving this error add `#include <stdlib.h>` in `gif_hash.h` file.

Now, build and run it's work.

Reference : [Github](https://github.com/osmandapp/Osmand/issues/2848)

Comment: It will give me error "'QtGlobal' file not found" in QtExtensions.h file, can you please help me